# jQuery Load problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having troubles with jQuery's load function and am hoping for some help.  I just started testing a site I built in IE to debug/hack/etc to make sure it works.  Firefox/safari/etc all work great.  .load won't work for me though.  It just seems to hang.  Would love some help.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#links").load("newfull.asp #Body");
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="links">
        test area
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page can be viewed at http://www.stephenkiers.com/2010/delete.html

Comment: Hmm, this is indeed rather odd. I noticed that if I used $.get to populate the data, I could retrieve the response, and load SEEMED to get data, but the links div just wouldn't be populated. IE8 doesn't hang, but it doesn't display data either.

Comment: The error was that I named the target ID Body which is already an HTML element.  That was messing IE up.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the path as an absolute URL instead of relative to the current document?

`$("#links").load("/path/to/newfull.asp #Body");`

A quick look at the jQuery page shows that relative URLs should be acceptable, but its worth a shot I suppose.

EDIT: Are you intending to use `#Body` to select the the body element or an element with the ID of `Body`?

Comment: I will change the name from Body.  That could be messing it up.  I should know better than to use HTML elements as ID names... tsk tsk

Answer (score 2):

From your question it's not exactly clear if you're only having a problem in IE, but when I hit the supplied page in FF, Chrome and Opera it loads as expected. When I browse to it in IE, I get a blank page as described. Thus, I'm assuming you experience the same thing and IE fails to render like the others.

Tracing the IE request in Fiddler I see the content page (newfull.asp) is requested and delivered, which suggests the problem lies in the jQuery selectors that are passed to the load call. Since it works in the other browser it seems like a quirk the IE DOM related to the specific page (or just a general bug with jQuery and IE). Usually when I hit such problems I check to see how well formed the markup is, and in this case there's a few [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.stephenkiers.com/2010/newfull.asp). It might be worthwhile to resolve the validation errors and see if it has an impact on IE's behavior.

Comment: It is now error free.  Good catch.  I didn't think of that.  To bad it doesn't affect it at all.

Answer (score 0):

$("#links").load("newfull.asp #Body");

try it without the space

$("#links").load("newfull.asp#Body");

Comment: IE8 developer tools rock, by the way.

Comment: did you actually try it or just try it with developer tools?
cause if you type newfull.asp #Body directly into ie nav bar, you get a 404 page

Comment: the space is what jQuery uses to determine what part of the page is returned.  So this request will ONLY return the #Body div from the requested page.